# How to prove this function is bounded?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

I've got the following function:

$v(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r^{2} - 1}{r^{2} + 1 - 2 r \cos\left(\psi - \theta)\right)}f(\psi)d\psi$

The function $f$ is NOT specified, but it is given that $f$ is continuous. We consider the function for values $r>1$.

How do I prove that $v$ is bounded for all $r>1$?

I thought about taking a derivative with respect to $r$, but got nowhere. I have been pulling my hair out over this one.

NOTE: The above function is the solution to $\Delta v = 0$ for $r>1$, with $v(1,\theta) = f(\theta)$.

Comment: You can start by showing that v is bounded as r goes to infinity.  That and continuity of v could get you there.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{r^{2} - 1}{r^{2} + 1 - 2 r \cos\left(\psi - \theta)\right)}\le \frac{r^{2} - 1}{r^{2} + 1 - 2 r } = \frac{r^2-1}{(r-1)^2} = \frac{r+1}{r-1} \to 1$$

when $r\to \infty$. So $v$ is bounded when $r$ is large.

Another point of view: for $r<1$, the function

$$\begin{split}
u(r, \theta) := v\left(\frac 1r , \theta\right) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\left(\frac 1r\right)^2  -1}{\left(\frac 1r\right)^2 +1 - 2\frac 1r \cos (\psi -\theta) } f(\psi) d\psi \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 -r^2}{1 +r^2 - 2r \cos (\psi -\theta) } f(\psi) d\psi
\end{split}$$

can obviously be extended to $r = 0$. Indeed this $u$ satifies $\Delta u =0$ and $u = f$ on the boundary $\{r=1\}$. So your $v$ is formed by "flipping" this $u$ from $\{r<1\}$ to $\{r>1\}$.

Comment: With regards to your first suggestion, I see that this implies that $v \to \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\psi)d\psi$ as $r\to \infty$. But how does this implies that $v$ is bounded? I mean for example, the function $g(r) = \frac{1}{r-2} + 1$ goes to $1$ as $r \to \infty$, but it is not bounded. So what else must I utilize?

Comment: If it goes to one, then it is bounded for $r \ge R_0$ for some big $R_0$, Then use that $v$ is continuous in the annulus region $\{ 1\le r\le R_0\}$. @Greg.Paul

Comment: Thank you, that is very clever! This would require the use of the fact that v is harmonic in the annulus, so that the maximum is attained on the boundary of the annulus correct?

Comment: @JohnMa How is $\frac{1}{r-1}$ bounded for $r>1$?  As $r\to 1^+$ this term approaches $\infty$.

Comment: No it doesn't @Dr.MV . I didn't say that.

Comment: @Greg.Paul : Yes, You could use that if you know that already.

Comment: @JohnMa But the task is to show that $v$ is bounded for $r>1$.  It is indeed bounded.  Unfortunately, showing that it is less than $1/(r-1)$ does not show this unless, as in your comments, your take $r>R_0>1$.  Then, yes, it is bounded for $r>R_0>1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV : A harmonic function does not have interior maximum. So we are done if we can show that it does not blow up at infinity... (It said: But it is given that $f$ is continuous")

Comment: Yes, but one would need to show that $v$ satisfies $\nabla^2 v=0$.  And given that $v$ is harmonic, we would need to prove the maximum principle.  Else this exercise is trivial.  I believe that the OP is tasked with showing that $v$ is bounded directly from the integral.   One might ask "why is the solution given in integral form" if we can handle the problem given only that $v$ is harmonic and $f$ is continous?  But, I might be wrong. ;-))

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I started out with the BVP $\Delta v = 0$ for $r>1$, and $v(1,\theta)=f(\theta)$ (where $f$ is continuous). So I know automatically that $v$ is harmonic. I also know about the maximum principles for harmonic functions inside bounded regions. If $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}v(r,\theta) = a\in\mathbb{R}$ then how does it follow that $v$ is bounded then just using the maximum principle?

Comment: Indeed you need something much weaker. You need only that $v$ is continuous on $\{r\ge 1\}$. If $v$ is bounded when $r >R_0$, then inside the region $\{1\le r\le R_0\}$, $v$ is also bounded as this region is compact. @Greg.Paul

Comment: @JohnMa One last question - where is it needed in this proof that $f$ is continuous? Do I need to suppose that $f$ is continuous in order to take the limit $\lim\limits_{r \to \infty}\{v(r,\theta)\}$? Other than that I can't see why i would need to suppose that f is continuous

Comment: You need to use continuity so that $v$ is bounded in the annulus region. @Greg.Paul

Answer (score 2):

First we will evaluate the integral $I(r)$ which is given by

$$\begin{align}
I(r)&\equiv \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r^2-1)}{r^2+1-2r\cos (\psi-\theta)}\,d\psi\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r^2-1)}{r^2+1-2r\cos \psi}\,d\psi
\end{align}$$

since the cosine function is $2\pi$-periodic.

We can evaluate $I(r)$ by making the substitution $z=e^{i\psi}$.  Then, for $r>1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
I(r)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(r^2-1)}{r^2+1-2r\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)}\,\frac{1}{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(i/r)(r^2-1)}{(z-r)(z-1/r)}\,dz\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

where we used the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to evaluate the contour integral.

Now, the function $v(r,\theta)$ can be written

$$\begin{align}
v(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r^2-1)}{r^2+1-2r\cos (\psi-\theta)}(f(\psi)-f(\theta))\,d\psi+f(\theta)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[0,2\pi]$.  Denote the supremum of $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ by $M$.  Then, we have for $r>1$

$$\begin{align}
|v(r,\theta)|&=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r^2-1)}{r^2+1-2r\cos (\psi-\theta)}f(\psi)\,d\psi\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(r^2-1)}{r^2+1-2r\cos (\psi-\theta)}\left|f(\psi)\right|\,d\psi\\\\
&\le M
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $|v|\le M$ and we are done!